# Scrapy Crawler: Build JSON file with right filter

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using CSS Class selector to help me out with a spider. On Scrapy shell if I do the following command I get the output of all the elements I need:

```
scrapy shell "https://www.fcf.cat/acta/2022/futbol-11/cadet-primera-divisio/grup-2/1c/la-salle-bonanova-ce-a/1c/lhospitalet-centre-esports-b"
```

I've modified the Spider with the suggestions I have received :

```
import scrapy


class ActaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'acta_spider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.fcf.cat/acta/2022/futbol-11/cadet-primera-divisio/grup-2/1c/la-salle-bonanova-ce-a/1c/lhospitalet-centre-esports-b']

    def parse(self, response):
        
        print ("[ PARSE START ]")
        
        temporada = response.css(".print-acta-temp::text").get()
        temporada = temporada.replace('TEMPORADA ','')
        print (temporada)
        
        acta_comp = response.css(".print-acta-comp::text").get()
        acta_comp_llista = acta_comp.split(' ')
        print (acta_comp_llista)
        
        for actaelements in response.css('table.acta-table tbody tr'):
            
            yield {
                'name': actaelements.css('a::text').get(),
                'link': actaelements.css('a::attr(href)').get(default='Link Error'),
        }
```

Now I need to build the JSON file according to the information on the 12 tables the webpage is built on. The JSON I'm trying to build should look something like this:

```
{
  "DadesPartit":
    {
      "Temporada": temporada,
      "Categoria": acta_comp_llista[1],
      "Divisio": acta_comp_llista[2],
      "Grup": acta_comp_llista[6],
      "Jornada": 28
    },
  "TitularsCasa":
    [
      {
        "Nom": "IGNACIO",
        "Cognom":"FERNÁNDEZ ARTOLA",
        "Link": "https://.."
      },
      {
        "Nom": "JAIME",
        "Cognom":"FERNÁNDEZ ARTOLA",
        "Link": "https://.."
      },
      {
        "Nom": "BRUNO",
        "Cognom":"FERRÉ CORREA",
        "Link": "https://.."
      }
      
    ],
  "SuplentsCasa":
    [
      {
        "Nom": " MARC",
        "Cognom":"GIMÉNEZ ABELLA",
        "Link": "https://.."
      }
    ],
  "CosTecnicCasa":
    [
      {
        "Nom": " JORDI",
        "Cognom":"LORENTE VILLENA",
        "Llicencia": "E"
      }
    ],
  "TargetesCasa": 
    [
      {
        "Nom": "IGNACIO",
        "Cognom":"FERNÁNDEZ ARTOLA",
        "Tipus": "Groga",
        "Minut": 65
      }
    ],
  "Arbitres":
    [
      {
        "Nom": "ALEJANDRO",
        "Cognom":"ALVAREZ MOLINA",
        "Delegacio": "Barcelona1"
        
      }
    ],
  "Gols":
    [
      {
        "Nom": "NATXO",
        "Cognom":"MONTERO RAYA",
        "Minut": 5,
        "Tipus": "Gol de penal"
      }
    ],
  "Estadi":
    {
      "Nom": "CAMP DE FUTBOL COL·LEGI LA SALLE BONANOVA",
      "Direccio":"C/ DE SANT JOAN DE LA SALLE, 33, BARCELONA"
    },
    "TitularsFora":
    [
      {
        "Nom": "MARTI",
        "Cognom":"MOLINA MARTIMPE",
        "Link": "https://.."
      },
      {
        "Nom": " XAVIER",
        "Cognom":"MORA AMOR",
        "Link": "https://.."
      },
      {
        "Nom": " IVAN",
        "Cognom":"ARRANZ MORALES",
        "Link": "https://.."
      }
      
    ],
  "SuplentsFora":
    [
      {
        "Nom": "OLIVER",
        "Cognom":"ALCAZAR SANCHEZ",
        "Link": "https://.."
      }
    ],
  "CosTecnicFora":
    [
      {
        "Nom": "RAFAEL",
        "Cognom":"ESPIGARES MARTINEZ",
        "Llicencia": "D"
      }
    ],
  "TargetesFora": 
    [
      {
        "Nom": "ORIOL",
        "Cognom":"ALCOBA LAGE",
        "Tipus": "Groga",
        "Minut": 34
      }
    ]
}
```

I would like some guidance on how to build it.

Thanks,
Joan

Comment: response.css(".print-acta-temp::text").get(), response.css(".print-acta-data::text").get(),response.css(".print-acta-comp::text").get(), response.css(".print-acta-jornada::text").get() These collect the basic data that should go on the JSON. Then the information contained in the tables. I need some guidance on how to build the JSON by appending infomartion depending on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much simpler than this with `requests` and `pandas`.You can do the following:

```
import requests as r
import pandas as pd
a=r.get("https://www.fcf.cat/acta/2022/futbol-11/cadet-primera-divisio/grup-2/1c/la-salle-bonanova-ce-a/1c/lhospitalet-centre-esports-b")
table_fb = pd.read_html(a.content)
```

You just have to index `table_fb` for the tables.

Here is the scrapy alternative:

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd

class stack(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ["https://www.fcf.cat/acta/2022/futbol-11/cadet-primera-divisio/grup-2/1c/la-salle-bonanova-ce-a/1c/lhospitalet-centre-esports-b"]    
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url, 
                callback=self.parse
            )
    def parse(self, response):
        tables = pd.read_html(response.text)
        yield {
            'table1':tables[0],
            'table2':tables[1],
            'table3':tables[2],
            'table4':tables[3],
            'table5':tables[4],
            'table6':tables[5],
            'table7':tables[6],
            'table8':tables[7],
            'table9':tables[8],
            'table10':tables[9],
            'table11':tables[10],
            'table12':tables[11],
            'table13':tables[12],
            'table14':tables[13],

        }
```

Comment: **@joe_bill.dollar** Thanks for your response. This is another approach that can be useful. At the end of the day, I'm just trying to learn and build something for my personal use. I have started a Scrapy Training, and I was trying to use with my hobby.

Comment: @futbolbasecelh I have added a scrapy alternative. when its easier and simpler to use `pd.read_html` with tables, always use this rather than css selectors. I would recommend using css selectors for selections that don't involve tables. The scrapy option is possibly better if you're scraping multiple links like this when you have differing number of tables.

Comment: **joe_bill.dollar** Thanks for the advice. I want to build a scraper that get all the links within all the fixtures within a season, and then drill down to the fixtures themselves to collect all the information. My aim is to build a database with all the data to then be able to create reports with PowerBi. Any advice on the best way to make the approach is welcomed. All the links are within this URL https://www.fcf.cat/calendari/2022/futbol-11/cadet-primera-divisio/grup-2